# What do exactly mean by "PHP compilation options"?

Tags: compilation, xampp, php-internals, php

I'm using **PHP 7.2.8** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I've installed **PHP 7.2.8** on my laptop using the latest copy of **XAMPP** installer.

I come across the following text from [Description of phpinfo() function from PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php#refsect1-function.phpinfo-description)

> Outputs a large amount of information about the current state of PHP.
>   This includes information about PHP compilation options and
>   extensions,......

I did not get what do exactly mean by "PHP compilation options" from the above text taken from PHP Manual.

I checked the output of `phpinfo();` by running it on my laptop.

I could only see the one line in output related to the compilation which is as below :

**Compiler  MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017)**

Is the above line mean the "PHP compilation options" mentioned in the PHP Manual or "PHP compilation options" is something else other than this?

If "PHP compilation options" means the same line I mentioned above then why there are not more than one compilation options present in the output of `phpinfo();` ?

Comment: That's merely one summary. Other settings are listed next with extension. Compilation options are not just the build tools, but everything you supply `./configure --…`. See also https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

Comment: Most configurations use the default options, they don't recompile with custom options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is written in C. C is a compiled language, meaning you use a C compiler to create an executable binary from the source. When doing so, you can pass numerous options to influence things in the resulting binary.

See http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php for a partial list of possible compile options. Quoting

> Most configure options are listed in their appropriate locations on the extension reference pages and not here. For a complete up-to-date list of configure options, run `./configure --help` in your PHP source directory after running `autoconf` (see also the [Installation chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php)). You may also be interested in reading the » [GNU configure documentation](http://www.airs.com/ian/configure/) for information on additional configure options such as `--prefix=PREFIX`.

The `phpinfo()` page usually contains a line listing the Configure options:

[image: example php info showing configure command]

For a more detailed explanation, check the chapter on bulding php in the PHP Internals book:

- http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/build_system/building_php.html

Comment: [the link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/gordon) in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) is broken